# Facebook debugger to not see contents inside conditional render (typeof window !== 'undefined')

Tags: next.js, facebook-opengraph, hydration

I fixed hydration issues in my NextJS application following this article https://blog.jannikwempe.com/react-pre-rendering-and-potential-hydration-issue. I deferred content render until user data is loaded.

```
const isBrowser = (typeof window !== 'undefined')
(isBrowser && IsMounted && <div>{children</div>)
```

The warning does not show up anymore but when I use facebook debugger to extract meta tags, I see that the content inside the condition above is not being rendered when I view the code via facebook scraper. I checked the source in the browser, and I can see the code with all the meta tags as well. Is there a way to fix this and ensure crawlers can see the content inside the condition?

Comment: If you want content to be visible to crawlers, it needs to be generated on the server-side. With your current code you're forcing rendering on the client-side only. What was the original hydration issue you were having?

Comment: It showed up a warning on console that said next-dev.js?3515:25 Warning: Did not expect server HTML to contain a <div> in <div>. and the above fix, fixed it.

Comment: While it may fix the hydration issue, it'll force the children of that component to be rendered on the client-side only. You need to address the specific cause of the hydration mismatch rather than applying a generic fix. Providing the code for where the hydration issue was happening would be helpful.

Comment: I have the exact same issue after moving to chakra-ui 2.x. How did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete the .next folder created and build again.
2. Check the console in the browser. There should be some errors. For me, it was that I moved from React 17 to React 18. In one of my components I was returning <></> You should have some errors in the console about nesting